# Posting Malicious Code for Review

Tags: discussion

I recently redirected my studies to the field of security. For learning purposes, I took a virus that we wrote as part of an assignment last year and improved it so it actually does something instead of infecting and printing "hello i am a virus". Since this was one of my first experiences with C, I would like to get some code reviews on how my code can be improved (not the virus but the actual code). Therefore I am thinking about posting the code on the Code Review however, given the code is malicious and actually works, I am a little bit concerned and couldn't really find any guidelines about this. Anyone have experience with this or any knowledge?